Ways to select 4 components from a list of 12 components, where 3 are manufactured by a, 4 by b and 5 by c, so that each has one compoenent selected.
I am trying to solve this problem, but it seems like my logic is incorrect, I'm just unable to understand what I'm doing wrong. The problem is:
A bin contains three components from supplier A, four from supplier B, and five from supplier
C. If four of the components are randomly selected for testing, what is the probability that each
supplier would have at least one component tested?
The way I am doing this is:

number of ways to select 4 components from 12 = $12 \choose 4$ = 495
Now, to calculate the number of ways where we get at least one component from each supplier:

ways to select 1 from supplier A * ways to select 1 from supplier * ways to select 1 from supplier C * ways to select 1 from rest of the (12-3 = 9) components
= $3 \choose 1$ * $4 \choose 1$ * $5 \choose 1$ * $9 \choose 1$ = 540
My understanding/arguement behind this logic is that, we want to make sure that we  select 1 component from each supplier to fill 3 out of 4 places. However, for the 4th place, it does not matter who is the component's supplier, which means, it can be either A, or B or C, hence the $9 \choose 1$.
However, this comes out to be greater than our sample space itself, which is impossible, and thus, my approach is clearly incorrect.  Im just unable to understand what is incorrect in my approach.

You need to consider three mutually exclusive cases, depending on whether the 4th component comes from A, B or C.  That is, you need to consider the mutually exclusive cases of $~(A,B,C) = (2,1,1), ~(A,B,C) = (1,2,1)~$ or $~(A,B,C) = (1,1,2).$

When performing the computations in my last comment, which should yield the right answer, and then considering why your computation is too high, consider the issue of over-counting.  That is, consider whether a specific situation is counted more than once.  For example, if A yields Part-A1 and Part-A2, this situation is counted twice.

I would use inclusion-exclusion.  How many ways to select 4 components without the restriction?  Exclude the cases where any one supplier was missed.  But we have over-compensated and must add back the cases of all from one supplier.

Here are two approaches to compute the numerator.
Direct:
$$\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2} = 270$$
Inclusion-exclusion, where the three properties to be avoided are $A=0$, $B=0$, and $C=0$:
$$\binom{12}{4}-\left[\binom{3+4}{4}+\binom{3+5}{4}+\binom{4+5}{4}\right]+\left[\binom{3}{4}+\binom{4}{4}+\binom{5}{4}\right] = 270$$
